# At what fraction of the speed of light have people traveled?

Tags: speed-of-light, rocket-science

I'm guessing that, this would be someone in a rocket or something...  When they hit their top speed, at what fraction of $c$ are they traveling?

Comment: lurscher's answer is absolutely correct... if you don't specify what the speed is relative to, the answer is any fraction you like.

Comment: Speed of Earth around Sun is velocity=107,300 km/h ? Don't we all travel at this speed ? Does this count ?

Comment: @Andrei, no. Doesn't count.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maximum velocity attained by the Apollo spacecraft was 39,897 km/h which is $3.6\times 10^{-5}$ times the speed of light...

Comment: remember this speed was relative to earth....if you want to pump it up a bit further add up the speed of earth moving (around sun), sun moving(around the milky way) and the milky way moving(with respect of I don't know what... ) :P...

Comment: @VineetMenon: I suppose that would be the velocity of the Milky Way with respect to the CBM, which is about 600 km/s I think.

Comment: By comparison Earth's rotational speed at the equator is 1674 km/h, so the above speed might need to be corrected by at most 1674 km/h if one wants the Apollo astronauts' speed with respect to a specific person standing on Earth's surface.

Answer (score 23):

When swinging my comfy hammock, I travel all day even up to 0.99 $c$, some days even more, depending on what particles are passing me by and measuring my exorbitant speeds with their atomic clocks and photons..!

Comment: Great job on thinking outside the box!