# Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Initially, we derive two dimensional equation for Schrödinger time independent equation. Then how it becomes three dimensional by just multiplying by delta. 
How?

[image]

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform We can derive it , its complicated

Comment: I would be pretty sure AFT is pulling your leg a little :),  but he is right, no q.m book can show you a derivation of the S.E., any more than a  math book derives an axiom. So your sentence is an assumptions or misunderstanding on your part.

Comment: @catapillar No , not a rigorous derivation. But enough to give a basic idea to Mast-p2

Comment: I thought S.E. was derived from conservation of probability, the measurement axiom, and the correspondence principle?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "two-dimensional" or "multiplying by delta" here. The "delta" is the Laplace operator and there isn't any two-dimensional equation in what you posted.

Comment: @InquisitiveMind I made a similar "derivation" [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293063). However, these type of "derivations" are not actual derivations of that equation. Instead, you should think of it as being ways to show that that equation (postulate) is reasonable. S.E is a postulate of QM. It is supposed to coup with the observations and experimental data.

Comment: You misunderstood it. The "inverted delta" there is the [**nabla**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol) operator (a "vector" with the form $\nabla =\frac{∂}{∂x},\frac{∂}{∂y},\frac{∂}{∂z}$). In one space dimension it just becomes $\frac{∂}{∂x}$.

Comment: Laplace operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator

Answer (score 1):

You have completely misunderstood it.Initially, we derived three dimensional equation for Schrodinger time independent equation. The term

$$ {\nabla^2\Phi}$$ 
is actually the double differentiation of $\Phi$ in three coordinates x,y,z .
It is the Laplacian Operator.It means double differentiate x by keeping y,z as constant and so on.

Comment: Right.  $\nabla$ is not $\Delta$.  It's defined right in the text.