# Reaching the speed of light, rockets

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity, rocket-science

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double light speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11398/double-light-speed)
>   [Someting almost faster than light traveling on something else almost faster than light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30505/someting-almost-faster-than-light-traveling-on-something-else-almost-faster-than)

Well I've been wondering quite a long time about this problem. If you had let's say 10 rockets, each of them having a length enough to provide space for an acceleration of another rocket inside. Each rocket would accelerate from 0, to 1/10 of speed of light. From the observers point of view, wouldn't the last rocket achieve the speed of light (since the speeds add up).

Comment: I know that you need infinite energy to accelerate an object of a certain mass to the speed of light, but the rockets, are not even approaching the speed, so that doesn't work here.

Comment: so what you are saying, that comparing the speeds of rocket 9,10 ,their speed difference would be much smaller than 1/10 of the speed of light, but from the rocket nr 10 point of view, the difference would be exactly 1/10 speed of light