# Relative velocity of two objects travelling at $c$ (or near $c$)

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, velocity

If two bodies are travelling at speed $0.9 \, c$ in opposite directions, what will be the speed of one, as observed by another? Newtonian mechanics won't apply at such speeds. As such, how will we calculate the actual speed? The speeds can obviously not cross $c$. How to intuitively understand this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula

Comment: There are [many related questions already on the site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=relativistic+addition). I've suggested what looks the most obvious duplicate.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23625/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory of relativity tells us what is the answer to this question. See Wikipedia, as John Rennie recommends,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_case:_parallel_velocities

If in the formula

$$v_{rel} = \frac{v_1 + v_2}{1 + v_1 v_2/c^2}$$

you set $v_1 = v_2 = 0.9 \, c$, you get $v_{rel} = 1.8/1.81$, i.e. slightly less than $c$.
But if you set $v_1 = v_2 = c$, you get $v_{rel} = c$.

To your attention, recent works on the gravity theory show that the velocity of light is a function of the configuration of the universe. In the early universe the value of c was probably different of what is today, (see in the arXiv quant-ph the works of Asher Peres and/or Danny Terno). Still, whatever is its value, the light velocity cannot be exceeded.

With pleasure,
Sofia

Comment: "In the early universe the value of c was probably different of what is today" - is this widely accepted?

Comment: @pfnuesel: No, but there are some theories on the [variable speed of light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_speed_of_light).