# How to prove that the Einstein velocity addition is a one-parameter composition formula of a one parameter group?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, velocity, group-theory, inertial-frames

How to prove that the Einstein velocity addition is a one-parameter composition formula of a one parameter group?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23625/2451 and links therein.